# Modifying Wordpress plugin does not reflect the change

Tags: wordpress

I haved tried to modify the css of a plugin `background-color: blue` . I have added in the correct file:

```
.woocommerce ul#shipping_method {
    display: none;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Inspecting the shipping method I can see the code is just `display:none`. I also see the css file from which this css comes, and opening it on "Sources" would not display my change.

I have also tried to override the file in my child theme like: 
Parent structure of the file :

```
/wp-content/plugins/shipping-zones-by-drawing-for-woocommerce/assets/szbd.css
```

Child structure :

```
/wp-content/themes/my-theme/shipping-zones-by-drawing-for-woocommerce/assets/szbd.css
```

Still I can only see the original css file in the Google Chromes's Sources tab.

Maybe it has something to do with the way it is loaded in the .js file: `wp_enqueue_style('shipping-del-aro-style', SZBD_PLUGINDIRURL . 'assets/szbd.css', SZBD_VERSION);`

Comment: firstly, if you are altering the actual plugin files itself, then its not ideal. could be cache issue?

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: Throw !important on the end and see if your issues persists. Also try in incognito mode. If none of these exists then it's not loading your css file right. If it does work, your css does not hold enough weight or matches the weight of the original style that's called later than yours.